# Integration problem involving $\sqrt{\cos(x)-\cos^3(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals, radicals, substitution

Evaluate
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\cos(x)-\cos^3(x)}\,dx.$$
Please help

Comment: the answer says 4/5

Comment: but for me the answer coming as 4/3

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Use $$\cos{x}-\cos^3x=\sin^2x\cos{x}.$$

We obtain:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin{x}\sqrt{\cos{x}}dx+\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^0\left(-\sin{x}\sqrt{\cos{x}}\right)dx=-2\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\cos{x}}d(\cos{x})=$$
$$=-2\frac{\sqrt{\cos^3x}}{\frac{3}{2}}|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{4}{3}.$$

Comment: Thanks..now i am sure the answer is 4/3

Comment: The answer mentioned in the book was 4/5 which is completely wrong..

Comment: You are welcome! I think it was typo.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Notice that for $x\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$,
$$\sqrt{\cos(x)-\cos^3(x)}=\sqrt{\cos(x)(1-\cos^2(x))}=|\sin(x)|\sqrt{\cos(x)}$$
Hence
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\cos(x)-\cos^3(x)}dx=
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\cos(x)}\sin(x)dx=-\frac{4}{3}\left[\cos(x)^{3/2}\right]_0^{\pi/2}=\frac{4}{3}.$$

Comment: I did it but i am not getting the answer as 4/5...i dont know whether 4/5 is correct or not..But my answer coming as 4/3

Comment: That's the main reason o have put the question here..

Comment: The correct answer is $4/3$.

Comment: Thanks robert..

Answer (score 0):

for the indefinite integral we get $$-\frac{2}{3}\frac{\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)\sin^2(x)}}{\sin(x)}+C$$